# How to combine code coverage summary of all spec tests in Cypress?

Tags: code-coverage, cypress

I'm currently using Cypress' [code coverage plugin](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage) to gather the coverage information. However, the plugin appears to reset the code coverage at the start of every spec it runs.

In other words, if I have 3 feature specs (`Spec A`, `Spec B` and `Spec C`) in my `integration` folder, the coverage will be reset at the beginning of each spec test. The final coverage report it saves is only the results for `Spec C` because the results are being reset and then overwritten at every run of each spec.

This is how I'm currently running the test:

```
nyc cypress run --spec './src/integration/login/*'
```

Instead of getting the code coverage information of each spec test, I would like to get the overall code coverage result for all the specs that I have for the application.

Is there a way in Cypress where I can get the end to end code coverage summary of all the spec tests instead of just individual spec test?

Comment: Are you running them individually or specifying the specs in one run, e.g [specifying multiple test files to run](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run-spec-lt-spec-gt)

Comment: @eric99 I have updated my question with how I'm running the tests. I am running them by their folders.

Comment: Still not quite clear if all of SpecA, SpecB, SpecC are all under `integration/login` (in which case you should be getting a combined result), or if you want the combined results for multiple runs (which I don't think is currently supported). If the latter is true, I have some mods that should help, but please clarify.

Comment: Also need to see your project folder structure, as `'./src/integration/login/*'` implies you have the specs along side the source, as opposed to the default `cypress/integration` folder which would require a spec path of `--spec './integration/login/*'`

Comment: @RichardMatsen I'm using Cypress with Cucumber. So I have a bunch of Gherkin feature files in `./src/integration/login/*`. When I run with `--spec './src/integration/login/*'`, the tests run fine, which I believe implies that the test is able to find the files from the right place. However, the coverage info is reset at the start of running each feature file and saved at the end of running each feature file. What I really want is a combined coverage summary/report of all the feature files being run. In other words, the coverage info shouldn't reset at the start of running each feature file.

Comment: Cheers, I haven't run with Cucumber so my info may not be applicable.

Comment: @RichardMatsen But the way they are run in Cypress I believe is largely the same as with regular spec files.

Comment: Ok, there's not enough info to give you an answer so this is just a pointer to a possible cause. Check out this method [filterSupportFilesFromCoverage](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage/blob/bd9b6ba8071026cd298eba65aa22bee0a1023685/support.js#L35) which is there to remove support folder files from the coverage stats, without the need to specify them specifically in nyc config. Since you have specs in a non-standard folder, this *may* be the cause - depends on how what you have in `cypress.config`.

Comment: @Carven, could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71605624/how-to-generate-only-test-coverage-from-a-specific-folder-with-tests-in-cypress . Will help me a lot

Comment: @Carven I had the same issue, Did you resolve this issue?
I think in interactive mode, cypress coverage will reset for each spec file. I couldn't find how to set the interactive mode as false.

Comment: @XiaoWang Unfortunately, I haven’t had a good solution to this problem I had. I settled for having 2 different values instead of combining them.