# How to generate only test coverage from a specific folder with tests in Cypress

Tags: next.js, cypress

I was reading Cypress docs and noticed that Cypress can generate `index.html` file inside `coverage/lcov-report/index.html`. That file contains the information about test coverage from the entire application. 
 Inside `cypress/` folder i have another folder called `main`.
Question: How to generate the coverage result only taking into account the tests from that folder? At the end when i will open `index.html` file i need to see only the coverage from `main` folder. 
 Who can help with that? Or probably is possible to configure `nyc`?

Answer (score 2):

Add some [configuration](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#common-configuration-options) to `nyc.config.js`

> **Using include and exclude arrays**
>
> If there are paths specified in the include array, then the set of instrumented files will be limited to eligible files found in those paths. If the include array is left undefined all eligible files will be included, equivalent to setting include: ['**']. Multiple include globs can be specified on the command line, each must follow a --include, -n switch.

Comment: there i can set the files that should be in test coverage, but i did not find a solution to include in the test report only a folder with tests not with eatures but with tests as i described in my question. Could you help?